# Cheap and Secure Proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm looking for cheap secure proxy providers that support

- vpn
- http
- socks

like this one http://www.your-freedom.net/.

Because I wish to compare their efficiency. YF(http://www.your-freedom.net/) 
doesn't provide my satisfaction on speed they provide after purchasing the account. 
Their try-before-buy account has much more speed than the purchased one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [It's Hidden](http://itshidden.com/)

The name `your-freedom.net` sounds like something i would avoid, just because of the name alone. The site itself seems to be a default look of some cookie-cutter web template you could find on the web for free. Even their logo makes 0 sense.... Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Hmm, I think their logo is a padlock being unlocked... when in fact I would have thought that a locked padlock would make more sense if you're talking about security. Anyhoo +1 for your closing paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

[ipredator](https://www.ipredator.se/?lang=en) comes into my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally used http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/ when I want to bypass non-US blocking.

There's a fairly small list of proxies at http://www.privax.us/ - no breakdown on which services they support though.

Answer (score 0):

Freegate is a great option, as is Your Freedom if you're using it for a limited amount of browsing(their free accounts have a few restrictions, but provide enough for browsing). (BTW, for the user who commented previously, Your Freedom is a reputable group in the circumvention community)

Other options that come to mind are:

- HotSpotShield
- UltraVPN
- Privoxy
- GPass
- UltraSurf
- TheWorld Browser
- Psyphon
- Alkasir
  All of those are free services concieved for censorship circumvention, I'm not sure what your needs are exactly, most of them gain efficient speed for surfing depending on the location/regime your operating in. HotSpotshield offers paid accounts.